# Converting multi-nested array into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to convert this array, into one array as shown below. How can I accomplish this with a method that will work, regardless of the level of nesting in the array.

```
var array = [1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]
//Output = [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question. That question does not address varying degrees of nesting.

Comment: The original question does not ask that though. So technically this is not a duplicate.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15030117/1447675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive function for this.

```js
var array = [1, [2], [3, [[4]]]];

function flatten(ar) {
  var result = [];

  ar.forEach(function(e) {
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      result = result.concat(flatten(e));
    } else {
      result.push(e);
    }
  })

  return result;
}

console.log(flatten(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it recursive!

```
result = [];

function covert(array) {
for (var b in array) {
    if (typeof b === number) {
        result.push(b)
    } else {
        convert(b)
    }
}
```

}